# Auth0 Login with PayPal

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, auth0

I'm trying use Auth0 to do a social login with PayPal and other social logins. The other social logins work perfectly, but when I initiate with PayPal I get the error message:

> Looks like this action is not supported. Please return and report this
>   error so that we can support it in the future. (invalid client_id or
>   redirect_uri)

The client_id and redirect_uri, along with everything else, are exactly according to spec. Any insight?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi. Were you using the Developer Keys? Or had you entered all your own app?id and app_secret?

Comment: I was using my own client_id and app_secret

Comment: having the same issue. anyone?

Comment: @Nexus23 I posted my solution as an answer below

Comment: Oops, sorry @mjabraham didnt' realise you were using Auth0. My issue is using .net stack.

Comment: @Nexus23 So I also did it using javascript, originally -- I found the problem usually lay in the stupidest things in the developer dashboard --- (a) make sure you relogin to the paypal developer dashboard every few minutes or however long it takes before it kicks you off without telling you. (b) watch for trailing spaces on your urls, client_id's and app_secret's (c) it takes a WHILE for changes to propagate sometimes. I've had it take up to a day.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem using the *possibly* recently created PayPal Sandbox option in Auth0.  I may have just not seen it before, but it solved the problem on my dev machine.